# Laravel array_diff attributes

Tags: php, laravel, array-difference

I'm trying to implement a `RecordsActivity` trait like in the Birdboard example on Laracasts.  Here's [Jeffrey's code](https://github.com/laracasts/birdboard/blob/20656248b1b68b1fcd04f3218d4956144dc927d2/app/RecordsActivity.php#L91) updated for Laravel >=5.7:

```php
/**
 * Fetch the changes to the model.
 *
 * @return array|null
 */
protected function activityChanges()
{
    if ($this->wasChanged()) {

        // weirdness here, see below
        dump(
            $this->oldAttributes, 
            $this->getAttributes(), 
            array_diff($this->oldAttributes, $this->getAttributes())
        );

        return [
            'before' => Arr::except(array_diff($this->oldAttributes, $this->getAttributes()), 'updated_at'),
            'after' => Arr::except($this->getChanges(), 'updated_at')
        ];
    }
}
```

The `dump()` above produces the below response during the test (without annotations).  Nothing changes between the two arrays, and it's obvious that one row is different, but somehow array_diff is failing.

```php
// $this->oldAttributes
array:14 [
  "name" => "890 Gleichner Lights Suite 446"
  "address" => "890 Gleichner Lights Suite 446"
  "city" => "Mantetown"
  "state" => "CT"
  "postal_code" => "00627"
  "active" => false
]

// $this->getAttributes()
array:14 [
  "name" => "890 Gleichner Lights Suite 446"
  "address" => "Changed"
  "city" => "Mantetown"
  "state" => "CT"
  "postal_code" => "00627"
  "active" => false
]

// array_diff($this->oldAttributes, $this->getAttributes())
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

> array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] ) :array
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and **returns the values in array1** that are **not present** in any of the other arrays.

So if one field's value is set empty, change the order cannot work too, for example: *set the `"address" => ""`, then `array_diff($this->getAttributes(), $this->oldAttributes)` will return `[]` too.*

> array_diff_assoc ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] ) : array
>
> Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference. Unlike array_diff() the array keys are also used in the comparison.

Use `array_diff_assoc` is better:

```php
$changes = array_diff_assoc($this->oldAttributes(), $this->getAttributes);
```

Comment: +1 for considering the array keys, but this doesn't solve the problem.  `array_diff_assoc()` also fails.

Comment: @Erich the comparison is **key with value**, so it will return `array("address" => "890 Gleichner Lights Suite 446")`.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but on my end, it's producing nothing (`[]`) and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Erich that's wried, I try those two array with `array_diff_assoc`, and it return what I expect...

Comment: I somehow got it working but not sure exactly why.  I copied the arrays to local variables and then did `array_diff` on them, which worked.  Then I switched it back to the original code, and that works now as well.